# how to get index of element in phpquery

Tags: phpquery

I'm trying to get index of div which contains 'Shop Name'
like:

```
$doc = phpQuery::newDocument($shops_page);
echo $shop_index = $doc->find(".shop_item:contains('Shop Name')")->index();
```

in JQuery `$(".shop_item:contains('Shop Name')").index();` works

How can i find index using phpquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ($doc->find(".shop_item:contains('Shop Name')")->length()){
$shop_index = $doc->find(".shop_item")->index(pq($doc->find(".shop_item:contains('.shop_item:contains('Shop Name')')")));
}
```